# How can I make hair strands look less sharp?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, hair

I'm attempting a hair render in EEVEE. The problem is that I can see the individual strands of hair too clearly in the render. How could I make the hair strands blend in a bit more so that we can no longer see indivifual strands of hair so easily? If you view the attached image in full resolution you should see what I mean.[image: Hair render]